# Why is my cloth colliding so weirdly?

Tags: physics, collision

I am trying to simulate cloth on top of an umbrella, that's blowing in the wind. Right now I'm already struggeling with the cloth clipping through the base of the umbrella.

I tried isolating a single beam of the umbrella's base and have some cloth fall onto that. This only worked rather well, when the beam was parallel to the ground. As soon as i tilted the beam, the simulation got all weird and blocky and started clipping and moving by itself.  [Reference GIF here](https://gph.is/g/ZkbQ7O1)

I'm also [attaching the .blend](https://we.tl/t-YfIAgF7X9S) file so you can check out what I'm trying to do. The basic situation is [image: this]

Comment: It helps if there is thickness to the cloth and the collision objects. Also remember that cloth needs to have a highly subdivided mesh to work correctly.